# Word meaning to repeat what another person is saying as a form of mockery?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when a kid repeats what his/her mother is saying because he/she is angry.

Answer (score 4):

They might be mimicking, mocking or parroting the person, more likely mimicking.

> **mimic**
>
> *verb*
>
> imitate (someone or their actions or words), especially in order to entertain or ridicule.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mimic

Comment: I'd write *mimick*

Comment: @Boondoggle  The verb is _mimic_ https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mimic. Had the answer contained a reference, this would have been clear.

Answer (score 4):

I think 'parroting' is perfect for that. It means 'mimic' but also that the person speaking has not thought about the words they are saying.